# Double error message with remote data annotation mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, double, data-annotations

hi i am new to MVC and i am trying to use Remote Data annotation with additional fields to validate Name and last name. everything is working great but i am getting double error messages when the name and lastname already exists. how can i fix this problem?

This is my Data annotation:

```
    [DisplayName("Client Name")]
    [Remote("CheckClient", "Client", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Client already exists.", AdditionalFields = "ClientLastName, initClientName, initClientLastName")]
    [MaxLength(45, ErrorMessage = "Client Name can not be over 45 characters.")]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Client Last Name")]
    [Remote("CheckClient", "Client", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Client already exists", AdditionalFields = "ClientName, initClientName, initClientLastName")]
    [MaxLength(45, ErrorMessage = "Client Last Name can not be over 45 characters.")]
    public string ClientLastName { get; set; }
```

Comment: you mean that you have "last name is missing" and in addition to that "first name if missing"? Those error message appears directly or when you click on submit?

Comment: yes i got the error message for both fields when the client already exists in the database

Comment: so this message appears after clicking on the submit button

Comment: yes after clicking submit

Comment: ok but both remote are calling same method, that's normal? Normally, there is method for each field, isn't it?

Comment: normally yes but here i want to check if the client name and lastname of the client i am trying to create already exists in the database. So i thought i should call the method from both fields. But it turned out that you can do it from 1 field and when you press the submit button it will check both fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed the problem i just removed the remote annotation on the lastName, the functionality is still the same but the second error was removed. I thought i had to add the same annotation on the second field to be validated too.